# Como trabalhar com sessions no Silex

Tags: php, session, silex

Boa noite,

Estou com uma duvida em como incluir, alterar e excluir dados no Session do Silex. A documentação da API dele é muito simples e sem explicações.

É o seguinte:

Preciso criar uma sessão contendo um array de valores fiz assim para cria-la:

```
$app['session']->set('container',['nome'=>'fulano', 'idade'=>21]);
```

Agora começam as dúvidas.

1- Como eu faço para incluir mais valores nesta session? Ex. cidade=>São Paulo

2- Como eu faço para alterar por exemplo a idade de 21 para 30?

3- Como eu faço para excluir algo? ex: nome

4- Como eu faço para testar se a chave esta criada? Ex: Se eu quiser testar se a chave idade esta setada.

Obrigado

Comment: A primeira coisa que eu faria era debugar. Já tentou dar um `print_r(get_class_methods($app['session']))` ? Talvez lá tenha alguma coisa como `append` ou `add`

Comment: Cara, se o `Silex` trabalhar com "dot notation" igual a maioria dos frameworks, então talvez você apenas tenha que fazer `$app['session']->set('container.nome', 'teste');`

Comment: Wallace o Silex usa as bibliotecas do Symfony 2. Veja que documentação esclarecedora: http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Session.html#replace()

Comment: Wallace se eu fizer $app['session']->set('container.nome', 'teste'); isto vai criar uma nova sessão com o nome container.nome. Agora executando isto que você falou print_r(get_class_methods($app['session'])) ele me retonar todos os metodos que estão na documentação cujo o link eu passai ai acima. So que eu não consegui usa-los, na documentação não tem nenhum exemplo.

Comment: Você me fez instalar o `Silex`, cara! quero te ajudar :)

Comment: Agradeço muito.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depois de instalar o `Silex` e ler alguns artigos sobre `Symfony 2`, cheguei a uma conclusão bacana.

Por padrão, só é possível incluir na sessão do `Symfony 2` valores do tipo `chave/valor`.

É como se ele fosse feito pra ser usado assim:

```
$app['session']->set('nome', 'Wallace');
$app['session']->set('idade', '24 anos');
```

Mas, através de uma classe chamada  `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Attribute\NamespacedAttributeBag`, presente na pasta `vendor` (que faz parte das dependências do `Silex`), podemos utilizar o `Session` semelhantemente a um `Namespace` do PHP.

Veja teste que eu realizei como um exemplo:

```
include_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Attribute\NamespacedAttributeBag;

$app = new Silex\Application();

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SessionServiceProvider());

$app->get('/hello/{name}', function ($name) use ($app) {

    // defino o valor que será utilizado como namespace
    $bag = new NamespacedAttributeBag('container');
    // adicionamos a instância da Bag    
    $app['session']->registerBag($bag);


    // definimos os valores do container
    $app['session']->set('container/nome', 'Wallace');
    $app['session']->set('container/idade', '24 anos');

    $data = $app['session']->get('container');

    var_dump($data); 
   //Resultado: array(2) { ["nome"]=> string(7) "Wallace" ["idade"]=> string(7) "24 anos" }


    return '';
});

$app->run();
```

Ou seja:

```
$app['session']->set('container/nome', 'wallace');
```

é o mesmo que:

```
$_SESSION['container']['nome'] = 'Wallace';
```

Para encerrar o dia, espero que isso ajude!

### Respostas

> 1- Como eu faço para incluir mais valores nesta session? Ex. cidade=>São Paulo

```
$app['session']->set('container/cidade', 'São Paulo');
```

> 2- Como eu faço para alterar por exemplo a idade de 21 para 30?

```
$app['session']->set('container/idade', '21');
echo $app['session']->get('container/idade'); // 21
$app['session']->set('container/idade', '30'); // define um novo valor
```

> 3- Como eu faço para excluir algo? ex: nome

```
$app['session']->remove('container/nome');
```

> 4- Como eu faço para testar se a chave esta criada? Ex: Se eu quiser testar se a chave idade esta setada.

```
var_dump($app['session']->has('container/idade'))
```

E por fim, para acessar o array com todos os dados

```
var_dump($app['session']->get('container'));
```

Comment: Cara muito obrigado. Amanhã eu testo e lhe falo. Mas parece que assim resolve tudo. Por enquanto muito obrigado.

Comment: Completei a resposta :)

Comment: Deu certinho Wallace. Muito obrigado. Se você não se importar poderia me explicar como você achou esta biblioteca? Obrigadão mesmo.

Comment: @JoaoNivaldo, foi nesse link: [Symfony2 Sessions introduction](http://gnugat.github.io/2014/04/23/sf2-sessions-introduction.html#basics)

Comment: Por gentileza, marque a resposta como resolvida, caso tenha sido solucionado o problema, ok?